# Blazor Displaying roles from users ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, authentication, roles, blazor

Here I got my `GetUsers`

```
public List<IdentityUser> GetUsers()
    {
        SeeUsers = new List<IdentityUser>();
        var user = usermanager.Users.Select(x => new IdentityUser
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            UserName = x.UserName,
            Email = x.Email
        });
        foreach (var item in user)
        {
            SeeUsers.Add(item);
        }
        return user.ToList();
    }
```

This is my page

```
    <AuthorizeView Roles="Admin" Context="Beheer">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var user in users)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@user.UserName</td>
                        <td>@user.Email</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </AuthorizeView>
</AuthorizeView>
@code {
    List<IdentityUser> users = new List<IdentityUser>();
    List<IdentityRole> roles = new List<IdentityRole>();
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        users = UserService.GetUsers();
    }
}
```

the problem is I need to add the user role from `aspnetuserroles` to a table and I cant figgure out how to do it. 
I tried `rolemanager` but that would only give the `name` and `id` of a role and not the bound user to it.
Is there a way to get the info straight out of `aspnetuserroles`?

I want something like this 
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0utmQ.png)

Comment: Couldn't you just use the ID it returns in a query to get all the info you need?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ApplicationDbContext`, you should have access to the ASPNetRoles and ASPNetUserRoles tables through the EF Core API. You can skip the UserManager and RoleManager and build out a service (or add to your UserService) that gets the info you need direct from the Database. Once you have Users, Roles, and UserRoles you can construct view logic to display it all as needed.

Comment: Thanks it works! i was so tunnel visioned by role , user and userrole manager